# rbash does not work when set as the default shell for a user

Tags: command-line, bash

Even though `/etc/passwd` and `$SHELL` confirm that the default shell is rbash, the restrictions as described by rbash manual does not apply. 
For example, I can change directory with `cd`, I can change the `PATH`, etc.

However, when I manually type `bash -r`, all restrictions are in place.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Any ideas what is causing this behaviour?
Is there any workaround for Ubuntu as it seems to be working on CentOS?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522566/70524?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart the user session, either by logging out and back in or by rebooting the machine, to make the changes take place.

Comment: Many thanks Kulfy, indeed after the reboot, rbash behaves as expected